# Grouping by line items in mysql

Tags: mysql

i need the result of one column to be different on each row.

This is how the data appears:

```
Ticketnumber  Legnumber  Commission
100           1          50
100           2          50
```

This is how I need it to appear:

```
Ticketnumber  Legnumber  Commission
100           1          100
100           2          0
```

So when the legnumber = 1 I need the commission to group by ticketnumber, but when the legnumber > 1 the commission should be zero. I tried writing a case statement to no avail.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi, please post the sql-query that you have tried so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Group By` Attribute

```
SELECT Table1.TicketNumber, LegNumber
, CASE WHEN LegNumber = 1 THEN SUM(Table2.Commission) ELSE 0 END AS Commission 
FROM Table1 JOIN (SELECT TicketNumber, sum(commission) as commission
                  FROM table1
                  GROUP BY TicketNumber) table2
ON TABLE1.TICKETNUMBER = table2.ticketnumber
GROUP BY Table1.TicketNumber, LegNumber
ORDER BY Table1.TicketNumber, LegNumber
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/592f7/8)

Comment: If I just GROUP BY TicketNumber then I don't get the row for legnumber 2, I just get one row for TicketNumber 100.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and inner table

```
SELECT TicketNumber, LegNumber, 
CASE WHEN LegNumber = 1 THEN 
(SELECT SUM(Commission)  
FROM MyTable WHERE TicketNumber = MT.TicketNumber 
GROUP BY TicketNumber) ELSE 0 END AS Commission 
FROM MyTable MT
```

Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00a95/6

Comment: Wouldn't that `SUM` by `TicketNumber,LegNumber`, not just `TicketNumber` ?

Comment: Did you saw the fiddle? It is giving 100.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT TicketNumber, LegNumber, 
 CASE WHEN LegNumber = 1 
      THEN (select SUM(Commission) from Table1  group by ticketnumber   ) 
      ELSE 0 END AS Commission 
 FROM Table1 GROUP BY TicketNumber, LegNumber
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/976e9/2)

Answer (score 0):

I would use this solution:

```
SELECT
  t1.Ticketnumber,
  t1.Legnumber,
  CASE WHEN Legnumber=1 THEN t2.sum_commission ELSE 0 END Commission
FROM
  Table1 t1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Ticketnumber, SUM(Commission) sum_commission
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Ticketnumber
  ) t2
  USING (Ticketnumber)
ORDER BY 
  t1.Ticketnumber,
  t1.Legnumber
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf54f/1).